# Looking for search terms to describe 2D planar geometry on a cylinder

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for search terms or references that describe algorithms and mathematics in the area of 2D geometry on a periodic surface such as a cylinder. For some simple examples of things that are different to simple plane geometry

- A pair of segments on a cylindrical surface may have more than one intersection point.
- A point can be to the left and to the right of a line.
- Straight line segments can have endpoints that meet.
- A convex polygon can intersect itself

Is there anything interesting to read about 2D geometry on periodic surfaces? If I google the obvious [2d geometry on cylinder](https://www.google.com/search?q=2+geometry+on+cylinder&oq=2+geometry+on+cylinder&aqs=chrome..69i57.7262j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) then nothing interesting turns up. I'm guessing I'm using the wrong terms to describe what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe this could be of help: https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/e/97/files/2013/02/Cylindrical-Geometry-Thesis.pdf